# Having the current bank account information of an employee

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query to get for EmployeeId = 5625, the list of their related bank information :

```
    SELECT
   [E].[EmployeeId],
   ISNULL([AFB].BankInformationId, 0) AS BankInformationId,
   [BIS].[Label] AS [System],
   [BIT].[Label] AS [Type],
   [BI].[Label] AS [Bank Name],
   [BI].[AccountNumber],
   [BI].[HolderFirstName] + ' ' + [BI].[HolderLastName] AS [Holder Full Name],
   [BI].UpdatedDate,
   [BI].CreatedDate 
FROM
   [Employee] AS [E] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [AF_AdminFile] AS [AAF] 
      ON [AAF].[AdminFileId] = [E].[AdminFileId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [AF_BankInformation] AS [AFB] 
      ON [AFB].[AdminFileId] = [AAF].[AdminFileId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [BankInformation] AS [BI] 
      ON [BI].[BankInformationId] = [AFB].[BankInformationId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [BankInformationType] AS [BIT] 
      ON [BIT].[BankInformationTypeId] = [AFB].[BankInformationTypeId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [BankInformationSystem] AS [BIS] 
      ON [BIS].[BankInformationSystemId] = [BI].[BankInformationSystemId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [Currency] AS [Cur] 
      ON [Cur].[ID] = [BI].[CurrencyId] 
WHERE
   e.EmployeeId = 5625
```

The output of the query mentioned above :

```
EmployeeId  BankInformationId   System      Type     Bank Name      AccountNumber     Holder Full Name  UpdatedDate                     CreatedDate 
5625        25223               European    Salary   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2019-06-21  12:52:10.5583656    2019-04-09 17:30:26.5767272 
5625        9913                European    Salary   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2018-10-15  07:12:41.7955086    2017-05-30 09:47:35.2461420 
5625        18933               European    Salary   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXX          2018-10-01 05:52:37.7380577     2018-10-01 05:52:37.7380577 
5625        10920               Asian       Expenses lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526     2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526 
5625        10920               Asian       Unused   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526     2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526 
5625        25223               European    Unused   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2019-06-21 12:52:10.5583656     2019-04-09 17:30:26.5767272 
5625        19574               Asian       Unused   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2019-04-09 17:30:41.0204536     2018-10-15 07:08:26.6160286 
5625        9913                European    Unused   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2018-10-15 07:12:41.7955086     2017-05-30 09:47:35.2461420 
5625        1594                European    Unused   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2017-08-07 04:13:19.4727086     2015-04-20 15:52:05.7233965
```

I want to have the latest (as current) bank information for the BankInformationId=10920 the record having Unused type means that the account is no more used (and it is not a current)

```
EmployeeId  BankInformationId   System      Type     Bank Name      AccountNumber     Holder Full Name  UpdatedDate                     CreatedDate 
5625        10920               Asian       Expenses lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526     2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526 
5625        10920               Asian       Unused   lorem ipsum    lorem ipsum       XXXXXXXXX         2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526     2017-07-25 07:09:33.6450526
```

How to get the current/last account information knowing that :

- The account types are Salary, Expenses and Unused
- I want to get the current Salary and Expenses bank information that
  are still used (which don't have the Unused type yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE and add a row_number() based on the last updated date. Something like this;

```
;with T as(
   SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [E].[EmployeeId] order by [BI].UpdatedDate desc) rn,
   [E].[EmployeeId],
   ISNULL([AFB].BankInformationId, 0) AS BankInformationId,
   [BIS].[Label] AS [System],
   [BIT].[Label] AS [Type],
   [BI].[Label] AS [Bank Name],
   [BI].[AccountNumber],
   [BI].[HolderFirstName] + ' ' + [BI].[HolderLastName] AS [Holder Full Name],
   [BI].UpdatedDate,
   [BI].CreatedDate 
FROM
   [Employee] AS [E] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [AF_AdminFile] AS [AAF] 
      ON [AAF].[AdminFileId] = [E].[AdminFileId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [AF_BankInformation] AS [AFB] 
      ON [AFB].[AdminFileId] = [AAF].[AdminFileId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [BankInformation] AS [BI] 
      ON [BI].[BankInformationId] = [AFB].[BankInformationId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [BankInformationType] AS [BIT] 
      ON [BIT].[BankInformationTypeId] = [AFB].[BankInformationTypeId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [BankInformationSystem] AS [BIS] 
      ON [BIS].[BankInformationSystemId] = [BI].[BankInformationSystemId] 
   LEFT JOIN
      [Currency] AS [Cur] 
      ON [Cur].[ID] = [BI].[CurrencyId] 
WHERE
   e.EmployeeId = 5625
)
select [EmployeeId],BankInformationId,[System],[Type],[Bank Name],[AccountNumber],[Holder Full Name],UpdatedDate,CreatedDate
FROM T
WHERE rn=1
AND [TYPE]<> 'Unused'
and BankInformationId not in (select distinct BankInformationId from T where [TYPE]= 'Unused')
```